# Which browsers do not support animated gifs?

Tags: browser, cross-browser, gif, animated-gif

It's seems like all major browsers (ie, firefox, safari, chrome) support animated gifs. Though I've been reading that IE might not be faithful to high frame rates. Who doesn't support animated GIFs? Iphone safari seems to just fine. What about other mobile browsers?

Comment: Except for Firefox, *none* of the browsers support delays less than 60 ms.

Comment: Don't know if they did back in 2010, but Opera and Chromium work fine with faster GIFs as well. However, iOS Safaris do not (different than OS X Safari), it behaves the same as IE...

Answer (score 8):

Lynx, for example.

Or any other non-graphical browser will likely also have problems.

Source: see [this browser support matrix for GIF (and other image formats)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support).

Comment: True, but sort of a non-issue, I think.

Comment: @mangle: I'm assuming that you ask because you would want to make some sort of information accessible via an animated GIF. I'm also assuming that animation is a crucial part of what you want to convey. If you cannot rely on your users using a particular browser (e.g. IE in a corporate environment) then you should not rely on the browser being able to display the animation or images at all. The usual rules of accessibility apply.